# Get inner href of an href link with xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I just started out with Python and learning about xpath expressions.
I'm trying to get a div, an a class, look for the href inside the a class and then get the part of the href, then just continue with something.

div class: `dropdown-menu` and a class: `dropdown-item`

My url: `https://www.something.com/library/category/stuff`

My xpath expression: `response.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-menu']//a[@class='dropdown-item']//a[contains(@href, 'category')]")`

It just returns an empty string and I can't figure out why, please advice.

Comment: Please show us all your code, containing the link to the web page you are working on

Comment: I just ran it from the shell. To clarify, I just want to grab all "category" href's inside the div class, shouldn't I be able to do that?

Comment: Without seeing your code - run from shell or from normal IDE and the page you are working on we can't help

Comment: Also, what parser are you using? I suspect it's `lxml`, but you need to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an `<a>` can't really be nested inside an `<a>`, I suppose you meant to write two conditions for the same `<a>` here:

```py
response.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-menu']//a[@class='dropdown-item']//a[contains(@href, 'category')]")
```

That would be written like this:

```py
response.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-menu']//a[@class='dropdown-item' and contains(@href, 'category')]")
```

or like this (predicates, i.e. the filter conditions in the square brackets, can be chained and are evaluated one after another):

```py
response.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-menu']//a[@class='dropdown-item'][contains(@href, 'category')]")
```